# empty space displaying once we click on button

Tags: html, css

we have review tab in product page [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , please search using CTRL + F for "review"

[image]

once we click on "Be the first to review this product", it displaying like this , means complete design is spoiled

[image]

```
<div class="form-add">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Write Your Own Review') ?></h2>
    <?php if ($this->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>" method="post" id="review-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__("You're reviewing:"); ?>
            <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></span>
        </h3>

        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if( $this->getRatings() && $this->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('How do you rate this product?') ?> <em class="required">*</em></h4>
                <span id="input-message-box"></span>
                <table class="data-table review-summary-table ratings" id="product-review-table">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because When you click on link you  `.main-container` has `.col2-right-layout` and default it have `.col1-layout`.

Your `.col-main`  has `float:left` and `width:75%`, so you need to change css or you need to change class name.

Default layout has css:

```
.col1-layout .col-main {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

So you need to add css for other page like this:

```
.review-product-list .col2-right-layout .col-main {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Use this  .review-product-list .col2-right-layout .col-main{ } this css. it's work for me.

Comment: i added the code in extrenal css, is the code is reflecting in site ?

Comment: you are right, its working fine. but need some more modifications. please click on [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

& [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form) on top until "check delivery availability" there is disign issues in link2.

please help me to make like link1.

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem ?

Comment: may be it was cache issue, now your solution working. please help for few more modifications

Comment: Add short-description in your product ... which are missing so that your content are not view properly

Comment: short description is already there, as you see in other link. but in reviews page its not displaying, you can check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960500/display-text-price-in-proper-place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115273/discussion-between-mukesh-ram-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).