# Display text & Price in proper place

Tags: html, css

some texts are missing and Prices are not displaying in proper place as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form)

[image]

but its working fine [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) & i want to display like this.

[image]

```
.product-view .product-shop .price-box {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.price-box {
    margin: 7px 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.short-description .std li {
    color: #908983;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: they are in different page, maybe the other one wasn't updated with the content.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a floating issue. Add `clear: left` to `.price-info`

Comment: it fixed price issue, seems i have to add content in the other page right ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: in the second image, you can see `Device: apple iphone 4` that is missing in first image. i want to display that content in both links

Comment: That info has class `.short-description`, which already has `clear: both` assigned. If you add that, you probably won't need the `clear` on `.price-info`

Comment: once i add `clear: left` than price worked for me , for `short description` is i need to add the content in the page.
or can we display the content through css only ?